# How to send data from React.js to an API endpoint made with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, api, flask

I'm new to React.js and API's in general. I'm working on a project, that takes in a user's username and phone number, and stores it in a database. I've written the frontend in react. When the user hits submit, I want my program to post the relevant data to a local server, and retrieve it using a Python flask script that then stores it into a DB. Is this the correct way I should be doing this? If so, how do I implement this in my handleSubmit method? Here's what I have so far:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  let username =  target.username;
  let phone_num = target.phone;
    if (!check_name_valid(username)){
        alert('* must be your first and last name');
    }else if (!check_phone_valid(phone_num)){
        alert('* numbers only (ex. 1231231234)');
    } else {
        this.postRequest(event)
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

postRequest(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const username =  target.username;
    const phone_num = target.phone;
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({title: 'example'})
  }
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ username: username, phone: phone_num}));
    event.preventDefault(event);
}
```

I get the following javascript error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch".

And here is my flask code (still working on it, just trying to get the post to work):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/test')

class LogInfo(Resource):
    def get(self, name, num):
        return {"username": name, "phone number": num}

api.add_resource(LogInfo, "/test/<string:name>/<int:num>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

and I get the following message from the flask api: "127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2023 16:36:48] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -"

Comment: Wrong path probably. You should show your flask endpoint as well

Comment: @Konrad Just added the endpoint, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your flask API expects GET request. By changing `def get` to `def post` you can change the http method to POST, which you are looking for.

On this line `api.add_resource(LogInfo, "/test/<string:name>/<int:num>")` the API is expecting to receive name and num as url parameters. To keep it simple, this should be changed to `/test`. You are posting the data in request body (without url parameters) which is good practice. Just change the request body in the handleSubmit method to include the username and phone_num data instead of example. `body: JSON.stringify({username, phone_num})`

Usually saving user data to database is done on the server side. Change the flask API code to something like this:

```
class CreateUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        user_data = request.get_json()
        username = user_data["username"]
        phone_num = user_data["phone_num"]
        
        // Todo add user to db

        self.response["status"] = 201
        self.response["message"] = "User created successfully"
        return self.response, 201

api.add_resource(CreateUser, "/test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

It's common to return the http status (201 created in this case) so the frontend knows what happened in the backend. To add to that, you could for example make the flask API return error if the username already exists and cannot be added to database.